# Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined in console using validate.js codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm using validate.js for form validation . I also tried jQuery and form validation it throws the validation message "this field is required" so , i have tried for the first time the validate.js. My requirement is  the input box should be red and the error messages should not be displayed .

here is my script for reference ,

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/validate.js"></script>

<script>
(function() {
  // These are the constraints used to validate the form
  var constraints = {
    email: {
      // Email is required
      presence: true,
      // and must be an email (duh)
      email: true
    },
    password: {
      // Password is also required
      presence: true,
      // And must be at least 5 characters long
      length: {
        minimum: 5
      }
    },
    "confirm-password": {
      // You need to confirm your password
      presence: true,
      // and it needs to be equal to the other password
      equality: "password"
    },
    username: {
      // You need to pick a username too
      presence: true,
      // And it must be between 3 and 20 characters long
      length: {
        minimum: 3,
        maximum: 20
      },
      format: {
        // We don't allow anything that a-z and 0-9
        pattern: "[a-z0-9]+",
        // but we don't care if the username is uppercase or lowercase
        flags: "i",
        message: "can only contain a-z and 0-9"
      }
    },
    
    country: {
      // You also need to input where you live
      presence: true,
      // And we restrict the countries supported to Sweden
      inclusion: {
        within: ["SE"],
        // The ^ prevents the field name from being prepended to the error
        message: "^Sorry, this service is for Sweden only"
      }
    },
    zip: {
      // Zip is optional but if specified it must be a 5 digit long number
      format: {
        pattern: "\\d{5}"
      }
    },
    "number-of-children": {
      // You don't have to input the number of children but it you do
      // you need to input an integer > 0
      numericality: {
        onlyInteger: true,
        greaterThanOrEqualTo: 0
      }
    }
  };

  // Hook up the form so we can prevent it from being posted
  document.querySelector("form#main")
    .addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      handleFormSubmit(this);
    });

  function handleFormSubmit(form) {
    // First we gather the values from the form
    var values = validate.collectFormValues(form);
    // then we validate them against the constraints
    var errors = validate(values, constraints);
    // then we update the form to reflect the results
    showErrors(form, errors || {});
    // And if all constraints pass we let the user know
    if (!errors) {
      showSuccess();
    }
  }

  // Updates the inputs with the validation errors
  function showErrors(form, errors) {
    // We loop through all the inputs and show the errors for that input
    _.each(form.querySelectorAll("input[name], select[name]"), function(input) {
      // Since the errors can be null if no errors were found we need to handle
      // that
      showErrorsForInput(input, errors && errors[input.name]);
    });
  }

  // Shows the errors for a specific input
  function showErrorsForInput(input, errors) {
    // This is the root of the input
    var formGroup = closestParent(input.parentNode, "form-group")
      // Find where the error messages will be insert into
      , messages = formGroup.querySelector(".messages");
    // First we remove any old messages and resets the classes
    resetFormGroup(formGroup);
    // If we have errors
    if (errors) {
      // we first mark the group has having errors
      formGroup.classList.add("has-error");
      // then we append all the errors
      _.each(errors, function(error) {
        addError(messages, error);
      });
    } else {
      // otherwise we simply mark it as success
      formGroup.classList.add("has-success");
    }
  }

  // Recusively finds the closest parent that has the specified class
  function closestParent(child, className) {
    if (!child || child == document) {
      return null;
    }
    if (child.classList.contains(className)) {
      return child;
    } else {
      return closestParent(child.parentNode, className);
    }
  }

  function resetFormGroup(formGroup) {
    // Remove the success and error classes
    formGroup.classList.remove("has-error");
    formGroup.classList.remove("has-success");
    // and remove any old messages
    _.each(formGroup.querySelectorAll(".help-block.error"), function(el) {
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
  }

  // Adds the specified error with the following markup
  // <p class="help-block error">[message]</p>
  function addError(messages, error) {
    var block = document.createElement("p");
    block.classList.add("help-block");
    block.classList.add("error");
    block.innerHTML = error;
    messages.appendChild(block);
  }

  function showSuccess() {
    // We made it \:D/
    alert("Success!");
  }
})();
</script>
```

My form

```
    <form id="main" class="form-horizontal" action="/example" method="post" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input id="confirm-password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" name="confirm-password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="username">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 messages">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input id="birthdate" class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" name="birthdate">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="country">Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <select id="country" class="form-control" name="country">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="zip">ZIP Code</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input id="zip" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="12345" name="zip">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="number-of-children">Number of children</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input id="number-of-children" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Number of children" name="number-of-children">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I'm getting this error in console [image]

while submitting the form error is triggered. I dont know where the problem is !